# break down into smaller queries

Tags: sql-server, divide-and-conquer

With much help from people here last week, I was able to complete a rather complex request. BUT now I am being asked (or suggested) to break the query into multiple simple queries, rather than the complex one. 
The current query is:

```
select i.IncidentNumber,
   r.unit_type, 
      r.unit,
      r.arv_dttm as Onscene_time,
   r.clr_dttm as Clear_time,
      datediff(minute, arv_time, clr_time) as time_diff
from (select CADIncidentNumber, 
         unit_type, unit, 
                  arv_dttm, 
                  clr_dttm,
                 arv_time,
                 clr_time,
         sum(case when unit_type = 'Ambulance' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by CADIncidentNumber) as ambulance_cnt,
         count(*) over (partition by CADIncidentNumber) as cnt
  from dw_prod.dbo.vw_unit_response 
  where CallTypeGrp2 = 'ALS' 
     and unit_type in ('Ambulance', 'Medic', 'Paramedic Engine', 'Paramedic Truck', 'Paramedic Tower', 'Paramedic Rescue Engine', 'Paramedic Brush Engine', 'Paramedic Rescue Squad')
  and DATEDIFF(DAY, arv_dttm,GETDATE()) < 8 
     and datediff(minute, arv_time, clr_time) > 5 
     ) r
left join INC_UnitInformation u on u.IncidentNumber = r.CADIncidentNumber
left join INC_Incident i on i.IncidentNumber = r.CADIncidentNumber
where ambulance_cnt > 0 and cnt >= 2
and not (u.PrimaryRoleOfUnit = 411000 or u.PrimaryRoleOfUnit = 411005) 
and r.unit_type not like 'Ambulance'
group by i.IncidentNumber, r.unit_type, r.unit, r.arv_dttm, r.clr_dttm, 
r.arv_time,r.clr_time
having COUNT(i.IncidentID) < 2
and sum(case when u.EMSUnitNumber like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
order by r.arv_dttm
```

The query's result needs to include "Ambulance" in its values, which it does right now. There is no problem with the query result. I'm just trying to see if this complex query can be broken down into multiple smaller queries glued joined together. Other than the function to count and ensure the ambulance value is included in the result, I don't think this is all that complicated, but I don't know....

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to break this into multiple queries? Just doing that for the sake of doing it is kind of silly. There must be some reason you were asked to do this.

Comment: Proper formatted SQL is so much easier to read and to understand.

Comment: The reason is to avoid the potential performance issue and resources stuck up. Although the current query does not take a long time to run and spit out the result, but yeah.

Comment: So you are going to break this into multiple queries using a non-standard technique to deal with a performance issue that doesn't exist? This is bad practice known as premature optimization. It is not a good thing.

Comment: I agree, if it runs correctly and quickly, it looks fine as-is.  Leave it alone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way I see I to break your query down into multiple (two) queries, is to take your derived table:

```
from (select CADIncidentNumber, 
         unit_type, unit, 
                  arv_dttm, 
                  clr_dttm,
                 arv_time,
                 clr_time,
         sum(case when unit_type = 'Ambulance' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by CADIncidentNumber) as ambulance_cnt,
         count(*) over (partition by CADIncidentNumber) as cnt
  from dw_prod.dbo.vw_unit_response 
  where CallTypeGrp2 = 'ALS' 
     and unit_type in ('Ambulance', 'Medic', 'Paramedic Engine', 'Paramedic Truck', 'Paramedic Tower', 'Paramedic Rescue Engine', 'Paramedic Brush Engine', 'Paramedic Rescue Squad')
  and DATEDIFF(DAY, arv_dttm,GETDATE()) < 8 
     and datediff(minute, arv_time, clr_time) > 5 
     ) r
```

And use it by itself to populate a table variable.  Then replace it with the table variable in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

Suggesting you to create a view for your inner query.

*Use appropriate names for your views.

```
create view view_1 select CADIncidentNumber, 
         unit_type, unit, 
                  arv_dttm, 
                  clr_dttm,
                 arv_time,
                 clr_time,
         sum(case when unit_type = 'Ambulance' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by CADIncidentNumber) as ambulance_cnt,
         count(*) over (partition by CADIncidentNumber) as cnt
  from dw_prod.dbo.vw_unit_response 
  where CallTypeGrp2 = 'ALS' 
     and unit_type in ('Ambulance', 'Medic', 'Paramedic Engine', 'Paramedic Truck', 'Paramedic Tower', 'Paramedic Rescue Engine', 'Paramedic Brush Engine', 'Paramedic Rescue Squad')
  and DATEDIFF(DAY, arv_dttm,GETDATE()) < 8 
     and datediff(minute, arv_time, clr_time) > 5 ;

select i.IncidentNumber,
   r.unit_type, 
      r.unit,
      r.arv_dttm as Onscene_time,
   r.clr_dttm as Clear_time,
      datediff(minute, arv_time, clr_time) as time_diff
from view_1 r
left join INC_UnitInformation u on u.IncidentNumber = r.CADIncidentNumber
left join INC_Incident i on i.IncidentNumber = r.CADIncidentNumber
where ambulance_cnt > 0 and cnt >= 2
and not (u.PrimaryRoleOfUnit = 411000 or u.PrimaryRoleOfUnit = 411005) 
and r.unit_type not like 'Ambulance'
group by i.IncidentNumber, r.unit_type, r.unit, r.arv_dttm, r.clr_dttm, 
r.arv_time,r.clr_time
having COUNT(i.IncidentID) < 2
and sum(case when u.EMSUnitNumber like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
order by r.arv_dttm
```